# How to add a delay between animations in AnimatorSet playSequentially()?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator, animatorset

I'm using AnimatorSet playSequentially method like this:

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
ObjectAnimator in = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
in.setDuration(2500);
in.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
ObjectAnimator out = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(splash, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
out.setDuration(2500);
out.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

set.playSequentially(in,out);
```

I would like to add a delay between animation 1 and 2, like this:

```
set.playSequentially(in,1000,out);
```

It is possible to add delays between animations using playSequentially method?

Answer (score 7):

Add this line of code:

```
    out.setStartDelay(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a start delay on the 2nd Animator (i.e. `out.setStartDelay(1000)`) before adding it to the set.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting a start delay on the individual animations,
use the `AnimatorSet.after(long delay)` function.

```java
AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();
s.play(anim1).after(1000).after(anim2);
```

[AnimatorSet.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.Builder#after(long))